# Automatic login in Bitbucket Page using Scala and Play framework through link?

Tags: scala, automation, playframework-2.0

Right now, I am working on an task where user download process takes place. Let us assume that i have a document in my bitbucket account, the link where the document is placed inside my account will be set in href="my//account/url" in my code, when user clicks the link, he will be directed to the login page and he will be asked to login, right now what i have to do is on showing the login page i have to automatically fill up username and password and login into my account where the user can download the documents. Is to possible to do it, if its possible can anyone of you guys show me how to do it, advance thanks guys.

Comment: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/oauth-faq-338365710.html
no need to use autofilling, login using oauth then you grant access to user managed things.

Comment: let me try it and come back to u.

Comment: sure, you can/should look at this example http://www.typesafe.com/activator/template/play-oauth2-scala

Comment: i tried with creating key and secret in http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/javascript/example/index.html but i am getting invalid consumer.

Comment: you should create them vi the way desciribed here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/oauth-faq-338365710.html

Comment: i got the consumer key and secret but can u show me any sample or example code or a link on how to post use those in scala post and gets access permission from the bitbucket (Access Token).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92115/discussion-between-vicky-and-huseyin-zengin).